# Joomla 3. How to limit max file size in custom field, created by plugin

Tags: joomla

How to limit max file size in custom field, created by plugin. My contact.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
        <fields name="params" >
                <fieldset name="params" >
                        <field
                                name="contact_file"
                                type="file"
                                label="PLG_CONTENT_TEST_CONTACT_FILE"
                                required="true"
                        />
                </fieldset>
        </fields>
</form>
```

Comment: The size of the file? This is a file that is already in your file systm? You say you are using a custom field bot isn't file a standard field type?

Answer (score 0):

the max file size will generally be set in the php-installation. You *can* set it like they say here: 
[Standard Joomla field types:File form field](http://docs.joomla.org/File_form_field_type)

meaning your xml will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
        <fields name="params" >
                <fieldset name="params" >
                        <field
                                name="contact_file"
                                type="file"
                                label="PLG_CONTENT_TEST_CONTACT_FILE"
                                required="true"
                        />
                        <field
                                name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
                                type="hidden"
                                default="1048576"
                        />
                </fieldset>
        </fields>
</form>
```

to allow 1 mb upload (at least that is how I understand the explanation in the link). This should add a html-hidden-field in your contact-form. Or you can  manually add a html-hidden-field in the contact-form, I guess.

regards Jonas